# What is the function of "_initLayout" in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, layout, catalog, session

What does this function do in magento?

```
$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
$this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
```

What `_initLayoutMessages()` return?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method returns nothing. Well, actually it returns `$this`.
From different parts of the application (mostly controllers) you can set session messages that are displayed in the next page you visit.
Here is an example.
When subscribing to a newsletter, when the page refreshes you will see a message `Thank you for your subscription.`.
This message is added from `Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController::newAction` by this line:

```
$session->addSuccess($this->__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
```

Where `$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')`.

By calling `$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');` inside an action you tell magento to show all session messages that were previously added by using:

`Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(...)` (or `addWarning`, `addNotice` and `addSuccess`).

Since the messages can be added by using different session parts (`customer/session`, `catalog/session`, `checkout/session`, `core/session`) this allows you to separate and control the messages that the user sees.

For example if on a previous action you added a message like this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError('Some error here');
```

the user won't see this message until he visits a page that maps to an action that has `$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');`.

Answer (score 4):

The method `_initLayoutMessages` adds a message block to the page layout that outputs any error, notice or success messages stored in the session model stated as argument.

So `$this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');` will output a message added via

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addError('foo');
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addSuccess('foo');
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addNotice('foo');
```